# How to customize svn date format

Tags: svn, date-format, svn-propset

I want to use `$Date$` for the autoset property during check-in, but want to have a means to modify its format. I just need to include the year information.

`$Date: 2015-06-05 00:49:43 -0700 (Fri, 05 Jun 2015) $:`

Can this be done through svn settings, or a custom property.

`$Date: 2015 $`

Answer (score 2):

Using [custom keywords](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.advanced.props.special.keywords.html) you can choose to use short format of date with `%d` format code. There is no format code for year only.