# TortoiseSVN - $LastChangedDate how to set globally in English days/months?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I'm wondering if that is possible to set.
I have an issue with special characters for days and months from a foreign country which is using special characters.

I want to set SVN `$LastChangedDate` in that way to set globally days/months in English language.
Is there a possibility?
I assume that days/months are taking from Regional Settings from Windows - how to omit this?

I've been looking for solving this issue but nothing concrete.
Changing regional settings in Windows also is not a solution.

Comment: Does any of these answer your question: [Setting date format for autoprop date in svn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30938296/setting-date-format-for-autoprop-date-in-svn) and [How to customize svn date format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30661445/how-to-customize-svn-date-format)